# How to set alarm with different time at one click button?

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I want to set 2 alarm with different time and saved it to sqllite database in one click button, and the first alarm was successfully displayed notification but at the time of the second alarm nothing happened.

**This is my code to add alarm** :

```
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                mHour1 = Integer.parseInt(jam1.getText().toString());
                mMinute1 = Integer.parseInt(menit1.getText().toString());

                values.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE, namaobat.getText().toString());
                values.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime()));
                values.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TIME, mHour1 + ":" +mMinute1);
                values.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_KEBERAPA, "satu");
                values.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_ACTIVE, "true");

                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mMonth);
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour1);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute1);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                long selectedTimestamp =  calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);

                new AlarmScheduler().setAlarm(getApplicationContext(), selectedTimestamp, newUri);

                ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();

                mHour2 = Integer.parseInt(jam2.getText().toString());
                mMinute2 = Integer.parseInt(menit2.getText().toString());

                values2.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE, namaobat.getText().toString());
                values2.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime()));
                values2.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TIME, mHour2 + ":" +mMinute2);
                values2.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_KEBERAPA, "dua");
                values2.put(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_ACTIVE, "true");

                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mMonth);
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour2);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute2);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                long selectedTimestamp2 =  calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                Uri newUri2 = getContentResolver().insert(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.CONTENT_URI, values2);

                new AlarmScheduler().setAlarm(getApplicationContext(), selectedTimestamp2, newUri2);
```

**and this is my AlarmScheduler class :**

```
    public void setAlarm(Context context, long alarmTime, Uri reminderTask) {
    AlarmManager manager = AlarmManagerProvider.getAlarmManager(context);

    PendingIntent operation =
            ReminderAlarmService.getReminderPendingIntent(context, reminderTask);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

        manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, operation);

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {

        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, operation);

    } else {

        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, operation);

    }
```

**this is my AlarmReminderService class :**

```
public class ReminderAlarmService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = ReminderAlarmService.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";

public static PendingIntent getReminderPendingIntent(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Intent action = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmService.class);
    action.setData(uri);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, action, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public ReminderAlarmService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = intent.getData();

    //Display a notification to view the task details
    Intent action = new Intent(this, Reminder_Activity.class);
    action.setData(uri);
    PendingIntent operation = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(action)
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Grab the task description
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    String title = "";
    String keberapa = "";
    try {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            title = AlarmReminderContract.getColumnString(cursor, AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE);
            keberapa = AlarmReminderContract.getColumnString(cursor, AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_KEBERAPA);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Pengingat Minum Obat", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Jangan lupa untuk minum "+title+" yang ke"+keberapa+" di hari ini ya! Karena kesembuhanmu sudah di depan mata.");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100})
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(operation)
            .setContentTitle("Pengingat Minum Obat")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Jangan lupa untuk minum "+title+" yang ke"+keberapa+" di hari ini ya! Karena kesembuhanmu sudah di depan mata."));

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
}
```